# Blutooth Peer To Peer Connection on iOS 7 using NSNetService

Tags: ios, nsconnection

I'm trying to get the Objective C++ distributed object model working between iOS and OSX devices. Using WiFi, almost everything is fine; however, with iOS 7 Apple introduced the "includesPeerToPeer" property which should publish an NSNetService over Bonjour using Blutooth. I set the property like this:

```
self.netService.includesPeerToPeer = YES;
```

before calling

```
[self.netService publish];
```

This works fine wetween a MAC and any iOS Device running iOS 7 (given, the MAC and the device are paired before). However, the devices don't discover themselves over Blutooth.

I'm wondering, whether I missed something or anyboldy has a glue, why this is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Well, got it. NSNetServiceBrowser now also has a new property called "includesPeerToPeer". When setting this to TRUE immediately after initialisation and before starting the search, devices find themselves.